# Will light bend in a circle on its own?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I found [this article](http://news.sciencemag.org/2012/04/light-bends-itself) and I didn't understand it. I did get that they were able to bend light to 360 degrees.

Does that mean if take a box that is completely empty, and shine a light into it, it will keep rotating in a circle inside?

What happens if I move the box?

Answer (score 4):

What the article talks about is [interference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_%28wave_propagation%29) - the way waves can interact if they have different phases (i.e. different amplitudes at the same point along the wave). When 2 wave peaks meet, you get double the intensity. When a peak meets a trough, they cancel each other out, and you get zero intensity.

According to the article, it has been proven theoretically at Technion, Israel Institute of Technology that by applying different phases to different parts of a spread-out wave, you can make the light appear to bend through any angle, even 360 degrees. Note that it is not the light beam itself that bends. Rather, the peaks in the light power appear along a curved path. Away from that path, the waves cancel each other, so no light appears there.

Independently of them, another team of scientists at the University of Franche-Comté found that they could use a [spatial modulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_light_modulator) to do this, and they managed to bend the resulting light by 60 degrees.

As the concluding paragraph of the article males clear, this is all explained by well understood laws of physics.

Comment: yes its explained by laws, however, i don't get how this is accomplished. Also about 2nd part of this question if it's bending using interference or anything else in vacuum will it keep going for a looong time or forever round in a circle.

Comment: The light rays themselves are not "bent", they keep going straight. Instead, there is a broad band of light which interferes with itself destructively everywhere, except along a circular path. And, it will only do that while the light is inside a small area; once outside, the rays will continue along straight paths.